# Ошибка "Stack around the variable was corrupted"

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть такой код, которые считает свободное место на диске:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD FreeBytesAvailable;

    GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
        L"D:",          // directory name
        (PULARGE_INTEGER)&FreeBytesAvailable,     // bytes available to caller
        NULL,     // bytes on disk
        NULL  // free bytes on disk
    );


    std::cout << FreeBytesAvailable;
}
```

Но, при завершении программы, вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменяйте тип FreeBytesAvailable на `unsigned __int64` или `uint64_t` https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/231497/info-understanding-and-using-getdiskfreespace-and-getdiskfreespaceex

Comment: очевидно, что функция ожидает `ULARGE_INTEGER` (64-х битное число), а передаёшь ты ей указатель на `DWORD` (32-х битное число)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция ожидает указателя на `ULARGE_INTEGER`, а вы почему-то передаете туда насильно приведенный указатель на `DWORD`. Неудивительно, что это ни к чему хорошему не приводит.

Объединение `ULARGE_INTEGER` содержит поле `ULONGLONG QuadPart` в качестве члена, который содержит все значение целиком. Так что если вы по какой-то причине не хотите просто воспользоваться `ULARGE_INTEGER` и настаиваете на подходе с "обычной переменной", то ваша переменная должна быть объявлена как `ULONGLONG`, а не как `DWORD`.